# Examples of $R$ on $A=\{1, 2, 3\}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I tried these questions to my best.

But I am not sure of their answers:

a) $\mathcal R$ is both symmmetric and antisymmetric:

$\mathcal R = \{ (1,1),(2,2), (3,3) \}$

b) R is neither symmetric or antisymmetric

$\mathcal R = \{ (1,1),(2,2), (2,3), (3,3) \}$

c) $\mathcal R$ is reflexive

$\mathcal R= \{(1,1), (2,2), (3,3)\}$

d) $\mathcal R$ is a function

$\mathcal R(x)  = x$

e) $\mathcal R$ is an inheritable function

(No idea)

Am I in the right direction with these, or no?

Thank you very much,
Andrew

Comment: The correct notation for a relation is $\mathcal R = \{ (a_0, b_0), \ldots, (a_n, b_n) \}$. For a function you can use the same notation or use $\{ a_0 \mapsto b_0, \ldots, a_n \mapsto b_0\}$ (`\mapsto` for the arrow) or $\mathcal R(a_0) = b_0, \ldots, \mathcal R(a_n) = b_n$, your example would be $\mathcal R(x) = x$.

Answer (score 1):

a) correct.

b) wrong. **Not antisymmmetric** asks for the existence of *distinct* elements $a,b$ such that $\langle a,b\rangle\in\mathcal R$ and $\langle b,a\rangle\in\mathcal R$. The relation you mention does not have that property. It is indeed not symmetric. This because $\langle2,3\rangle\in\mathcal R$ and $\langle3,2\rangle\notin\mathcal R$.

c) correct.

d) This is in my view too vague to be a legal answer in this context. The identity function must be recognized as the relation $\mathcal R:=\{\langle1,1\rangle,\langle2,2\rangle,\langle3,3\rangle\}$.

e) Unfortunately I don't know the definition of "inheritable function". I you have one then it is a good thing to add that to your question.